# Query sum of rows that are blank after the current row until the next non-blank row

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table. It has these columns, let's say:

```
OpeningBalance    ClosingBalance    SomeOtherValueIDontCareAbout
--------------    --------------    -----------------------------
22                 100              Foo
16                  84              Bar
                                    Har
                                    Tar
                                    Zar
                                    Bar
                                    Foo Bar
12                  16              Har
                                    Par
91                  126             Zoogle
                                    Proper
                                    Hello
21                  182             Sing
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You'll notice that some rows do not have values for neither the `OpeningBalance` nor the `ClosingBalance` columns.

At all times, the `ClosingBalance` is greater than the `OpeningBalance`.

We are to calculate the increase in balance (`ClosingBalance` - `OpeningBalance`) for a row. Then, we are to count how many rows below that row have blank values for `OpeningBalance` and `ClosingBalance` until a row that has values for them. Then, we are to display a summary like the one below.

```
Group               IncreaseInBalance        TotalRowsItAppliesTo
------------        ------------------       ---------------------
Group1               78                       1
Group2               68                       6
Group3                4                       2
Group4               35                       3
Group5              161                       1
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And that's an MS Access database we're dealing with. I'm totally lost. It's been a while I haven't touched SQL in any way, shape or form.

Kindly help.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the comments. I got this problem from a close friend of mine. Neither I nor him have any control as to the organization of the data. Had it been a choice, I would've designed the database from start by forking out two tables as one poster suggested.

Given that, I had a closer look at the data.

The data is sorted by two columns -- first by a string value called Location and then by a DateTime value called RecordingDate.

However, neither of these two columns might be relevant for the blank row thing. As in, about 200 rows belong to one location and a single date, and then another 100 or so rows to another date of the same location, and then another 200 rows of a different location with a different date. However, there are many blank rows even after the first row.

I hope you get what I am saying.

So, to ORDER BY, I don't think it'd be right to do that on the Location or the RecordingDate for counting blank row sets.

Isn't there some ##rowId thing like thing in the Jet database? I guess the organization that has this work supposes that the rows are to be considered the sequence in which they were entered into the database.

Is there a way out?

Comment: Isn't SQL a set-based language? There's no concept of "order" unless explicitly sorted... If at all possible, you should explicitly insert the OpeningBalance and EndingBalance for all tuples (rows).

Comment: As @voithos says, this is dependent on an ordered sequence, but SQL only guarantees an order if you have a column or columns that you can order by.  Are there any columns in your data set that can be used in an ORDER BY to order your sample data by?

Comment: You should probably have separate tables for storing these data: one would contain the balance values (without gaps!) and a key column, the other would contain rows with `SomeOtherValueIDontCareAbout` and a referencing column that would let you link the two tables together in a proper way. Then calculating the increase and counting relevant rows would be merely a matter of joining, grouping and aggregating.

Comment: I've just added an update. I don't know if that makes the situation any better. Any help, even if it means a "not possible" with some conviction and reasoning will help a lot. Thanks much.

Comment: "The data is sorted by two columns -- first by a string value called Location and then by a DateTime value called RecordingDate."  In that case, tell the db engine how to order the rows: `ORDER BY Location, RecordingDate`  Doesn't that duplicate the row ordering you're seeing now?

Comment: Thanks, guys.

@HansUp I am not sure what you meant by "doesn't that duplicate the row ordering you are seeing now?"

Comment: Does this query show you the same data in the same order as what you hope for when examining the table directly? `SELECT OpeningBalance, ClosingBalance, SomeOtherValueIDontCareAbout FROM YourTable ORDER BY Location, RecordingDate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot solve this with SQL alone, since SQL is not aware of the order of the rows. SQL treats tables as mathematical sets.

First, add a new column called "Group" as Long Integer to your table. Then execute this code to prepare the table

```
Public Sub PrepareBalance()
    Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim group As Long

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblBalance")
    Do Until rs.EOF
        If Not IsNull(rs!OpeningBalance) Then
            group = group + 1
        End If
        If rs!group <> group Then
            rs.Edit
            rs!group = group
            rs.Update
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close
    db.Close
End Sub
```

This adds a group number to each row. Now you can execute this query

```
SELECT
    tblBalance.Group,
    Max([ClosingBalance]-[OpeningBalance]) AS IncreaseInBalance,
    Count(*) AS TotalRowsItAppliesTo
FROM
    tblBalance
GROUP BY
    tblBalance.Group;
```

Comment: Ah! I see. So, basically add a new column to group by, using code or whatever. Yeah, I could do that. I'll let my friend know. Thanks for the solution. :-)